# Clarification on visa requirements when travelling to Russia for people from specific countries

Tags: visas, russia, tourist-visas

In the [Russian Visa Information](http://ru.vfsglobal.co.uk/visa_free_regime.html) webpage there are a list of countries that can travel to Russia without a visa.

For example:

> Brazil (up to 90 days in 180 days period except work, study and residence).
>
> People’s Democratic Republic of Laos (up to 90 days in 180 days period except work, study and residence).
>
> Panama (up to 90 days in 180 days period except work, study and residence).

So, according to this website, people from Brazil or Panama can go to Russia at any time and stay up to 90 days. And they can repeat the same again every 6 months. Is there any other requirement?

I am planning a visit to Russia to see an [air show](http://www.rusarmyexpo.com) and one of my friends is from one of the countries I quoted above, so I just want to make sure he is fine without a visa.

We will book a hotel for our stay (5 days).

Comment: I suggest you specify the exact country, as this would help us to find the exact requirements.

Comment: The exact country is Brazil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the official Russian sources (which are rather scarce on the real information), and I don't see any extra requirements.

Note that the information above does not come from an official source, and in case for Laos it [contradicts the official source](http://www.mid.ru/ru/maps/la/-/asset_publisher/oFjFiFMe57Wr/content/id/2963812) (the linked MFA statement says "up to **30** days", not "up to 90 days", and there is no 90/180 restriction).

And since you're staying in a hotel, you are not required to register with police (the hotel will do this for you).

Comment: I confirm that people with Brazilian passport can go to Russia without a visa - this was at least valid in 2018!